# Dynamic Pivot Table Range

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2013

I have 3 worksheets in my workbook.  
Sheet 1 - allows users to input a date range

Sheet 2 - returns the data from the date range

Sheet 3 - A Pivot table based off the data returned

I thought creating a table and setting the pivot table source as the table but when I click on the Insert option in the ribbon, Table is grayed out.  Maybe because the data is a refreshable query from an external source...

**Question**
 is there a way I can set the pivot table data source to adjust based off the amount of data that is returned on Sheet 2?  My pivot table will **always** need to span 12 columns, just the number of rows could fluctuate.

(other than manually rebuilding the pivot each time the query is refreshed)

Comment: Have you tried [dynamic named range](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html)? I haven't, so can't say if it will work, but it looks like it will. [another reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830287)

Comment: It looks like the dynamic named range will only work for one column, and merging 12 into a single Pivot Table is problematic. If your data is coming from a query, you should be able to build your pivot from that external source instead of from Sheet2.